# Android studio adding new methods a locked Class

Tags: android, inheritance

I am using android studio to build a messaging application and to do this I imported this class.

```
import co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView;
```

In this class there are receive and send message options. In receive message method it takes the current time and receives the message. Now, I want to store this messages and show them to user. The problem is that, to show this messages to user I need to be able to write a method like StoreMessages which will store the time of this messages and when I want to show the users this messages I need to make its time compenent equal to the value I have on database. But since I cannot change the receive method it always takes the current time. So how can I add a new functionality to this class?

I tried to copy the whole class into a new java file I created and my program crashed

This is the log cat error for the interested ones but the main focus of this question is how to achieve what I asked.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication/com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication.ChatActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView cannot be cast to com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication.ChatView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView cannot be cast to com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication.ChatView
                      at com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:38)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: If your program crashes, add the logcat to your question

Comment: I am adding it but my question is not about the error I get

Comment: You have two different `ChatView` classes. You can't cast one to the other. You should rename `com.example.sahilliolu.myapplication.ChatView` to something else to avoid confusion

Comment: You should also show this `ChatActivity.onCreate` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add functionality to a library, it's a better idea to use inheritance, rather just copy a whole file.

However, in the case where the code is tightly coupled (I assume I found the correct library), then you'll need to do some additional work.

```
public class YourChatView extends View {

    // This is your own adapter. 
    private MyChatViewListAdapter adapter;

    ... 

    public MyChatView(Context context) {
        this(context, null); 
    }

    public ChatView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ChatView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

        ...

        // You'd have to replace these with your own adapter
        adapter = new MyChatViewListAdapter(context);
        chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    ... 

    // Make this insert the timestamp you want
    private void setButtonOnClickListener() {
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long stamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String message = inputEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                    sendMessage(message, stamp);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Alternatively, if you are having problems completely swapping out that functionality, you can override these methods within your own subclass since they're public.

```
public void sendMessage(String message, long stamp) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, stamp, Type.SENT);
    if (chatListener != null && chatListener.sendMessage(message, stamp)) {
        chatViewListAdapter.addMessage(chatMessage);
        inputEditText.setText("");
    }
}

public void newMessage(String message) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, System.currentTimeMillis(), Type.RECEIVED);
    chatViewListAdapter.addMessage(chatMessage);
    notifyMessageReceivedListener(chatMessage);
}

public void newMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    chatViewListAdapter.addMessage(chatMessage);
    notifyMessageReceivedListener(chatMessage);
}
```

If you do copy out all this code an modify it, then make sure to use `CustomChatView` instead of `ChatView` in the Activity code. If you don't use `extends`, then you can't cast a `CustomChatView` to a `ChatView`, nor can you mix-and-match classes, and that's what the error is saying.

You can do similar things with the adapter class.

```
public class ChatViewListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...

    public void addMessage(ChatMessage message) {
        chatMessages.add(message);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Just extend `ChatViewListAdapter`, and override that `addMessage` method to do whatever you want.

```
public class MyChatViewListAdapter extends ChatViewListAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addMessage(ChatMessage message) {
        message.setTimestamp(0L); // Update to the time you want. 
        super.addMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: This was what I asked since I know about inheritance but dont know how to do it in Android Studio. Add message does the think you assume but it is used in the methods of  ChatView which are  receive messages and send message. Time info is also given in that methods. By the way can I do that in my own package?

Comment: I cannot do the thing you suggested since ChatViewListAdapter has no constructor, I cannot extend it

Comment: Android Studio isn't limiting your understanding of inheritance. It is all just Java. I see what you are referring to... You'd essentially have to re-write this library to get what you are asking for, I think

Comment: Why does it need a constructor?

Comment: I created a new class and pasted the code you wrote. I think when I extend it calls super() to get a constructor and fails so it gives me an error message but I may be wrong

Comment: There is no empty constructor, no, but there definitely is three others since it extends the `View` class and those are necessary.

Comment: To be honest, this has been the most instructive answer to a question I ve asked or read in SO. I will try the things you wrote but I think it will work since every step makes total sense. I am upvoting it and accepting your answer, I will write a comment later if any of these approaches work or fail